# phoneGap database creation example

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a database using phonegap's api: 
In order to do this I have used the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
        alert("database created");
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Db" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The buttone doesnt do anyting. The idea is that when the app starts I'm supposed to get confirmation that a database has been created. However this is not happening. Please help...

Comment: is your js location path is correct ?

Comment: "create a database using phonegap's api"  Sqlite DB support is HTML 5 feature. not a phonegap api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
**Hi check whether Deviceready fires or not  then try this **
```

function onDeviceReady() {

```
alert("onDeviceReady");

try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Browser does not Support this');
        } else {

            var shortName = 'DbName';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'DBName';
            var maxSize = 100000; // in bytes
            openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            alert('DB created');  
        }
    } catch(e) {
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version mismatch..
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error "+ e +".");
        }
        return;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in your js location path . I run your code and i didn't get any error.

Please check your path of your cordova.js . I think you put that js in js folder of `assets/www/js`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think 'alert()' works inside a webview as-is.  Try console.log() instead to output a message (if you are using eclipse), or some other method - perhaps changing the content of a div - to show you the results.